# Convert XML with namespaces and attributes into C# Model class

Tags: c#, xml

Can someone please help me with the following problem. I want to create a c# model class based on a xml file that have namespaces and attributes.

This is the xml File:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetAllowedCategoryTree xmlns="http://www.cdiscount.com">
            <headerMessage xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Context>
                    <a:CatalogID>1</a:CatalogID>
                    <a:CustomerPoolID>1</a:CustomerPoolID>
                    <a:SiteID>100</a:SiteID>
                </a:Context>
                <a:Localization>
                    <a:Country>Fr</a:Country>
                    <a:Currency>Eur</a:Currency>
                    <a:DecimalPosition>2</a:DecimalPosition>
                    <a:Language>Fr</a:Language>
                </a:Localization>
                <a:Security>
                    <a:DomainRightsList i:nil="true" />
                    <a:IssuerID i:nil="true" />
                    <a:SessionID i:nil="true" />
                    <a:SubjectLocality i:nil="true" />
                    <a:TokenId>${#Project#token}</a:TokenId>
                    <a:UserName i:nil="true" />
                </a:Security>
                <a:Version>1.0</a:Version>
            </headerMessage>
        </GetAllowedCategoryTree>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I dont know how to make a C# class model, with getter's and setter's for a xml tag like

`s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILE = @"c:\TEMP\TEST.XML";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILE);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "GetAllowedCategoryTree", Namespace = "http://www.cdiscount.com")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "headerMessage", Namespace = "http://www.cdiscount.com")]
        public List<HeaderMessage> headerMessage { get; set; }
    }
    public class HeaderMessage
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages")]
        public Context Context { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages")]
        public Localization Localization { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages")]
        public Security Security { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cdiscount.Framework.Core.Communication.Messages")]
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public int CatalogID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerPoolID { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }
    }
    public class Localization
    {
        public string CatalogID { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public int DecimalPosition { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
    public class Security
    {
        public string DomainRightsList { get; set; }
        public string IssuerID { get; set; }
        public string SessionID { get; set; }
        public string SubjectLocality { get; set; }
        public string TokenId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```